# Does multiplying a set of linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ by a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ result in a still linearly dependent set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Does multiplying a set of $k$ linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ by a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ result in a still linearly dependent set of vectors?

I believe this is true but I am not able to prove it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, this is far from being true. As long as the matrix $A$ is singular, the product $BA$ will be singular whatever $A$ is. Just take $A = 0_n$ for example.

Comment: @dezdichado I think you might have misread the question.

Answer (score 3):

Supoose for a particular vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $$\sum_{i=1}^k c_iv_i=0$$

where $\exists$ index $j$ such that $c_j \ne 0$,

Then we still have , $$\sum_{i=1}^k c_iAv_i=0$$